# How do I suppress stderr warning messages from a command inside command substitution?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, stderr

```
touch ~/deleted/$(echo "directory_"$(readlink -f foo)|tr '/' '\') 2> /dev/null
```

where foo is a directory

It's reading the full pathname of foo and creating it as a file replacing all '/' with '\' and putting a directory_ in front so the directory 
`/home/test/foo` would create a file `directory_\home\test\foo`

It does exactly what I want except a warning keeps printing `tr: warning: an unescaped backslash at end of string is not portable`

a. I don't know what that means
b. I would like it to not show

I tried to redirect stderr to `/dev/null` but it doesn't work. How do I suppress it?

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify how you use this. Are you calling it as a function? Where is `$1` defined? You should also be aware that while `\ ` are allowed in file names, it is a Very Bad Idea® to include them and it will lead to all sorts of trouble later on.

Comment: It's in a script. to run it I  "sh script nameOfDirectory"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify accordingly. I also strongly suggest you consider using _any_ other character but `\ `, backslashes are special as you're finding out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some expansions happen before redirection so you have to place it directly against your `tr` command:

```
touch ~/deleted/$(echo "directory_"$(readlink -f foo)|tr '/' '\' 2> /dev/null)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message means that you have an unescaped backslash. In the *nix world, special characters are 'escaped' by adding a backslash before them. That means that they're interpreted as simple characters and not special ones.  For example:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar'
foo
bar
```

The `\n` is a special character that means newline. But if we escape the slash we get:

```
$ printf 'foo\\nbar'
foo\nbar
```

So, you can get rid of it either by escaping the backslash:

```
touch ~/deleted/"$(echo "directory_$(readlink -f -- "$1")"|tr '/' '\\')
```

Or by redirecting the error output of `tr` (not of `touch` which is what you were doing):

```
touch ~/deleted/"$(echo "directory_$(readlink -f -- "$1")"|tr '/' '\' 2> /dev/null)
```

However, I cannot stress enough that **it is a Very Bad Idea®** to create file names with backslashes. Really. They will be hell to parse and deal with later on. Why not use another character?

Comment: Maybe the OP from windows environment?

Comment: @Gnouc yes, which means it's an even worse idea to use `\\`.

Comment: Git Bash in Windows 10 complains about `[...] | tr '\\' '/'` although the backslash is properly escaped. Go figure.

Comment: @Rolf Windows uses `\` as the path delimiter, so that might cause issues there.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes with double back slash, and you will not get any error.

```
touch ~/deleted/$(echo "directory_"$(readlink -f foo)|tr '/' '\\')
```

Comment: Fun thing is, if `url=D:\Programs\Git\mingw64/share/doc/git-doc/git-log.html` then ``url1=`echo $url | tr '\\\ '/'``` shows the warning, while `url1=$(echo $url | tr '\\' '/')` does not.